# Are snapshots of apps stored somewhere?

Tags: recents-screen

Had an instance recently where a 'snapshot' of an app appeared in the recently used section of my phone months after it was last opened. Wondering how this could happen if the app hasn't been physically opened? Is the image stored somewhere?

Comment: By snapshot do you mean an app screenshot in the recent app list?

Comment: By snapshot if you mean the image of the app that you see in the recent apps list then yes, it is stored by Android, but it is not accessible by any third-party app. That said, an app can show up in recent apps list when a user mistakenly presses on the icon of an app and immediately presses the icon of the app they wanted to press originally.

Comment: Based on the timing and for additional context, I believe the OP previously posted a "question" on [Where does Android store the snapshots used on the recent apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172913/44325) with the text: "*Follow up question, if the 'snapshots is no longer showing in the recently used app section does that mean the image has been deleted or can it be resurrected somehow?*"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Firelord thanks for the reply.. for a bit of context - had a live stream camera connected to an app on my phone a while back. Recently and without being opened, this app recently appeared in the 'recent apps' with the last image streamed (wasn't there previously). Was wondering how this could happen without opening the app and with the camera not being online. Phone has always been glitchy and opened apps of its own accord.