# Are the Android app switcher/multitasking snapshots created when an app is sent to the background, encrypted?

Tags: security, internal-storage, file-system, encryption, 9.0-pie

This post here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218963/364009

outlines the snapshots location for the app switcher when an app is sent to the background, /data/system_ce/userid/snapshots, or at least something similar for File Based Encryption Android phones running 9.0 pie and below.

Are these snapshots also encrypted in Full Disk encryption?

For Android 9 supporting File Based Encryption and up, (Android 10, 11, etc.), are these snapshots encrypted? If not, can they be recovered after a factory reset with special software?

See post here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/198080/364009

mentioning exceptions to directories that are not encrypted, like /system_ce, because their subdirectories are encrypted. Does this mean these snapshots are encrypted if /userid is also encrypted or /userid/snapshots is encrypted?

Thank you!

Edited for clarity of Android versions of interest and typo.

Edit 3/15: this link here:

https://github.com/corona-warn-app/cwa-app-android/issues/987

Says “When the app is sent to the background, Android takes a snapshot of the latest view of the application and saves it without encryption on the file system.” How is this possible - I would assume the snapshots would be encrypted?

Comment: Even files that are only encrypted with the device encryption key (thus they are not bound to the user secret) can not be recovered after a factory reset as al keys are erased on a factory reset.

Comment: Correct, but with file based encryption, aren't specific files now tied to their own key? So I wanted to make sure that these task switching snapshots specifically were encrypted, is that the case? I believe they were with full disk encryption.

Comment: Q1. FDE what do you expect remain unencrypted on **full**-disk encryption Q2. FBE "ce" = "credential encrypted" Q3. what is the difference

Comment: Does anyone know or can confirm that app snapshots are indeed encrypted?

Comment: @AndroidUser558 Can you define what you think 'encrypted' means given that the issue ticket referenced `Access to this location requires an attacker to have root privileges`

Comment: If those snapshots are not stored on the phone encrypted, then when the phone is factory reset and the encryption keys for anything else are wiped, those background snapshots would still be able to be retrieved. Then they wouldn’t even need root privileges, if they could just get it off the hard disk?